# Convert exe to apk

Tags: android, vb6, apk, exe

I have made an application in Visual Basic. Visual Basic automatically generates a standalone .exe file out of your project. I wanted to convert **that** application into an apk file to run on android devices. Can anyone please tell me how to do so?

Comment: Very easy - you simply cannot **convert** an exe into an apk

Comment: I wish it was that simple.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of an Android application is remarkably similar to that of a VB application, but even more like that of a WinRT application (which of course copied what iOS and Android do due to mobile realities).

But VB6 doesn't use the exact execution/lifetime model required, nor does it have the ability to create proper Android UI elements.  And the compiler doesn't generate code even remotely portable to an x86 Android device, let alone one using ARM hardware.

The closest thing to VB6 for Android is probably the [Basic4Android](http://basic4ppc.com/) product.  However it doesn't pretend to compile existing VB6 code, and the language syntax is somewhere between VB6 and VB.Net.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not possible.

You'll need to write your application again in a way that's compatible with running on Android. Either use the SDK, or turn it into a webapp.